# Mouseup event fires twice when changing records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a front end with a main form, frmHub, containing a subform which is a continuous form, frmData.  The user can cycle between values in a textbox control (txtType) on frmData, by shift-clicking the control. (There are only 3 possible values.)

It's all running ok but sometimes the Mouseup event runs twice, and I can't figure out why.  I have to use mouseup rather than click, to pick up the shift key.

Any idea how I can solve this, or suggestions for next steps? A google search has shown lots of hits for jquery and c# but none for Access, which makes me think I've just done something silly, but I'm stuck on where to go with it.

OK, while typing this I've seen a pattern: it only fires once if I shift-click on the same record. If I change records with my click, it fires twice. What's going on here, or, what can I do about it?

Here's my mouseup code.  (The Debug_Step() function just writes the specified text and current datetime into a table, I use it to hunt bottlenecks while developing.)

```
Private Sub txtType_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

Dim Marker As Long
Marker = Debug_Step("Start txtType_MouseUp")

Dim CurrentType As String
Dim NewType As String

If Shift = 1 Then

    CurrentType = Nz(Me.sType, "OFF")

    Select Case Button
    Case 1 'Left click demotes
        Select Case CurrentType
        Case "PBS"
            NewType = "PER"
        Case "PER"
            NewType = "OFF"
        Case "OFF"
            NewType = "PBS"
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
        End Select

    Case 2 'Right click promotes
        Select Case CurrentType
        Case "PBS"
            NewType = "OFF"
        Case "PER"
            NewType = "PBS"
        Case "OFF"
            NewType = "PER"
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
        End Select
    End Select

    Call Apply_sType(Me.ident, NewType)
End If

Call Debug_Step("End txtType_MouseUp", Marker)

End Sub
```

Edit: I'm on Access 2010; frmData uses a linked sql server table as its recordsource; frmHub uses a passthrough query.

Comment: off topic here but I like your `Debug_Step` system.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Access 2010. Which version do you use?

Comment: A workaround could be: catch the `Shift` information in the `MouseDown` event, store it in a module variable. Then move your code to the `Click` event, using the stored Shift status.

Comment: Access 2010 is what I'm using. I'll try that, thanks @Andre

Comment: Thanks, Gary :) I'd be happy to post or PM the code if anyone would find it useful.

Comment: Huh! That's weird. I tried what you suggested, and found that the click event ran, THEN the mousedown event, then the click event again. I wonder if it's firing the event on the form control first, and then the textbox control ON the form. But why would the mouseup and click fire on the textbox, but not the mousedown...?? O.o

Comment: will `lostfocus` event solve your purpose?

Comment: @GroovySu, Please share your debugging in MS Access Documentation. or create a Q and A

Comment: @Adarsh, what do you mean? (Sorry if I'm being an idiot...)

Comment: @GroovySu, I has suggested that you should create a Q & A for sharing your debugging technique.

Comment: you probably have a faulty mouse :)

Comment: Have you thought about using a boolean toggle? eventCodeRunning = true at start and eventCodeRunning = false at end, then use If eventCodeRunning = false then do stuff

Comment: Good idea, @Absinthe, but it fires twice in a row, starting again after it has completely finished the first time around, so I can't trap it that way.

Comment: @  GroovySu - use a click counter as well? ;D

Comment: @Absinthe - I'm interested in this workaround but can't figure out how it might work. So far not found a way to increment the click counter correctly. Also I need to find a way to replicate it! Grr...

Comment: @ GroovySu - If it consistently gets called twice then start your counter at 1 and record it in a table (or in some other persistent fashion). At the very start of your triggered code increment the counter. Then if (counter Mod 2 = 0) allow the code to run.

Comment: I feel a bit thick, I'm still not getting this. Say my counter is called iCounter. I initialise it: iCounter = 1. At the start of my triggered code, it increments, so iCounter = 2. It runs all the way through, then it runs again, so now iCounter = 3.  Presumably what we're after is, right at the start, if iCounter = 1 then run else exit. So at some point I've got to set it back to 1 again. If I set iCounter = 1 at the end of the code, then when it immediately runs again, it won't be prevented from running because iCounter does = 1 still. What am I missing?

Comment: When the second event runs, does it have the same  x,y coordinates? If so, you could save them and not run a second click from the same spot as the last one. If user can click from the same spot twice in a row and you want it to count, add time stamp to saved data and if x, y happens in less them n milliseconds, ignore it. Do some experimenting with n, computer probably duplicates the event a lot quicker than a human can.

Answer (score 0):

If still actual for someone. Noticed that kind of buggy thing happens in textboxes with RTF mode on.

Some workaround: make a boolean variable and set it to true inside of onCurrent event, than set it to false when first fire occures and exit, on second fire - run code of your procedure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).